# On Button Click - Change Span Content - More efficient way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for some assistance and there must be a better way to code this.  I have a series of buttons that change the same span Id and well I can get it to work but it seems like an excessive number of actions.  Is there a way to make this more efficient?  Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
        jQuery("#All-Btn").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery('#Type').html("red wine"); 
        });
        jQuery("#Awesome-Btn").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery('#Type').html("Awesome"); 
        });
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "more efficient"?

Comment: there are multiple ways. Best bet, data-attributes or switch/object based on id

Comment: Dekel, I am still real new to the programming world and I constantly find that while what I write works it is almost never the fastest, smallest, or more DOM efficient way.  Just seeking out the best alternative to what I put above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common Approach is using data attributes

```js
$("[data-test]").on("click", function () {
    var text = $(this).data("test");
    $("#out").text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-test="Red">Button 1</button>
<button data-test="Blue">Button 2</button>
<button data-test="Green">Button 3</button>

<div id="out"></div>
```

Another approach is a lookup

```js
var text = {
  btn1 : "Red",  
  btn2 : "Green",  
  btn3 : "Blue",  
};

$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#out").text(text[id]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="btn">Button 3</button>

<div id="out"></div>
```

Or a switch

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id"), 
        text;
    switch (id) {
      case "btn1" :
          text = "Red";
           break;
      case "btn2" :
          text = "Green";
           break;
      case "btn3" :
          text = "Blue";
           break;
    }
    $("#out").text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="btn">Button 3</button>

<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom function:

```
function myBtn(id, text) {
  $(id).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#Type').html(text);
  })
}

myBtn("#All-Btn", "red wine");
myBtn("#Awesome-Btn", "Awesome");
```

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for.  Thanks Chris! At the very least it reduces the length cause I have about 10 buttons... Thanks mate!

Comment: A shared class would be better, than having to call myBtn over and over.

Comment: @RossBethune You're welcome, but using a data attribute is indeed preferable here.

Comment: That is what I just implemented seems to be a lot less code in the end.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, provided you gave all your buttons a shared class and a data element you could reduce the logic as such.

```
<input type="button" id="All-Btn" class="typeButton" data-type="red wine">
<input type="button" id="Awesome-Btn" class="typeButton" data-type="some other value">

jQuery('.typeButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#Type').html(jQuery(this).data('type'));
}
```

Comment: Seems like this method is the chosen way.  Didn't know it could be done perfect!

Comment: You don't need a shared class given the buttons already share a `data-type` attribute.

Comment: You should avoid attribute selectors.  As a general rule you want to operate with selectors that can be comparable to the basic javascript lookups for performance reasons.  Any way you can keep jQuery from using Sizzle is a +++++

Comment: You'd have to have a pretty big page before you noticed a performance difference, and modern browsers can handle those selectors directly without needing Sizzle.

Comment: Doesn't mean you should abuse it, :)  Agree to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

You could make object, with key-value pairs: Key is button id, value is span html, e.g:

```
buttons={
'All-Btn':'red wine',
'Awesome-Btn':'Awesome'
};
```

And then iterate through it:

```
$.each( buttons, function( key, value ) {
jQuery("#"+key).click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery('#Type').html(value); 
        });   
});
```

```js
buttons={
'All-Btn':'red wine',
'Awesome-Btn':'Awesome'
};

$.each( buttons, function( key, value ) {
jQuery("#"+key).click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery('#Type').html(value); 
        });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="All-Btn">
fffff
</div>

<div id="Awesome-Btn">
fffffffffff
</div>
<span id="Type"></span>
```

However, you have to type... a lot, again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the text that you want to display as an attribute of the button (ex `data-text`). Then, you just need one function to handle the event

```
    jQuery("#All-Btn, #Awesome-Btn").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var text = jQuery(this).data('text');
        jQuery('#Type').html(text); 
    });
```

How about that?

Answer (score 1):

The first way that came to mind was to use a `data-` attribute to specify the text associated with each button, and then bind a single, delegated click handler to handle clicks on all buttons with that attribute.

Notice that then your buttons don't need IDs.

```js
$("body").on("click", "[data-text]", function() {
  $("#type").text($(this).attr("data-text"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="type">&nbsp;</span><br>
<button data-text="Awesome">Awesome</button>
<button data-text="Whatever">Something</button>
<button data-text="Greetings">Hello</button>
<button data-text="Fare well">Goodbye</button>
<button>This button does nothing because it has no data- attribute</button>
```

(I've bound the delegated click handler to the `body`, but the best practice is to bind it to the closest common parent of the elements in question.)